# How to save and retrieve image in asp.new mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

## How to save and retrieve image in asp.new mvc


i wanna upload photo to my asp.net mvc project

Comment: Show your code here. And please search on google you get the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the your View you must have input file like this:

```
<input type="file" name="yourImageTag" />
```

and in the controller you must have an action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage()
{
     if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
     {
         var file = Request.Files[0];

         if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
         {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
         }
     }

     return RedirectToAction("Every action");
 }
```

when you submit the form, this code save your attached image to the **Image** folder from root of the project.

and for retrieve image you must put the address like `~/Images/filename`:

```
<img  src="~/Images/filename" />
```